# Using `.match()` to separate data within braces {}

Tags: javascript, regex

I have data like

```
[{somevalue1},{somevalue2}]
```

I want to extract `datawithin` the braces

I used

```
var data = data.match(/[{][^\"]+[}]/g);
```

But I receive `null` value.

Comment: `.match` is a native JavaScript function, it has nothing to do with jQuery. You expression does not match because `[^a]` matches any character but `a`, so it matches up to `{somev` and then fails because the next character is `a` and not `}`. Why are you using `[^a]` at all?

Comment: Just to verify...the format of the string you supplied looks similar to JSON, although the objects aren't exactly correct JavaScript objects. You're not trying to manually parse a JSON-encoded string, correct? If you are, I'd highly recommend using this library instead...https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/

Comment: @HerroRygar yes. I am trying to parse Json manually..

Comment: If you use that library that I recommended above (written by the creator of the JSON standard, Douglas Crockford), all you will have to do is: `var data = JSON.parse(stringOfData);`. It's less error prone and safer...a much, much better alternative to trying to do it yourself.

Comment: @HerroRygar yes. Thank you. But i try it just for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
data = data.match(/\{([\w\s]*)\}/g);
```

\w will look for alphanumeric, and \s for spaces.

Comment: Why not use `[^}]*` instead of `[\w\s]` ? That'd account for special characters like `?` or `$` too.

Comment: `\{([^}]*)\}` would also be a possibility. Since I don't know what is the format that should be valid for the user, I preferred to just consider alphanumeric and spaces :)

Comment: When i used it, it took {somevalule1},{somevalue2} as a single element. Hence i changed it to 
      `data = data.match(/\{([^}]*)\}/g);`

Answer (score 1):

```
data=data.match(/\{([^}]*)\}/g);
```